# angular scope vs react state how does it work for data binding

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. I found that `props` & `state` are used in react for binding.

What is the core difference in Angular scope and ReactJS state?

Answer (score 2):

**Angular:** `$scope` by default is two way. When you use them in your HTML, Angular keeps track of every DOM use of $scope, and watches for updates from the user. The angular controller knows about it virtually instantly.

**React:** `state` by default is one way. Getting data back from React involves writing an onChange handler for each input. Also, those event handlers need to be bound to your `this` variable using `this.inputOnChange.bind(this)`.

For two way data binding in `React`, you could use something like **[twio](https://npmjs.com/package/twio)**. It eliminates your onChange event handler methods, simplifies your component interface, and handles `.bind(this)` for you.

```
import Twio from "twio";
class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      firstName: Twio(firstName => this.setState({firstName})),
      lastName: Twio(lastName => this.setState({lastName})),
      email: Twio(email => this.setState({email})),
      password: Twio(password => this.setState({password})),
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.firstName} 
          onChange={this.state.firstName.onChange} />
        <input type="text" value={this.state.lastName} 
          onChange={this.state.lastName.onChange} />
        <input type="text" value={this.state.email} 
          onChange={this.state.email.onChange} />
        <input type="password" value={this.state.password} 
          onChange={this.state.password.onChange} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I will give you my answer based on my somewhat old experience with angular.

**Angularjs:**
Angular's scope purpose is different than ReactJS `state` and `props` and the reason is actually based in it's inheritance structure. 
Based on [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) in angular github:

> In AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its parent scope. One exception to this rule is a directive that uses scope: { ... } -- this creates an "isolate" scope that does not prototypically inherit.（and directive with transclusion） This construct is often used when creating a "reusable component" directive. In directives, the parent scope is used directly by default, which means that whatever you change in your directive that comes from the parent scope will also change in the parent scope. If you set scope:true (instead of scope: { ... }), then prototypical inheritance will be used for that directive.

Angular's scope is basically meant to evaluate expressions and create two way data binding, react's solution is different.

**ReactJS:**

A little note about the difference between state and props
based on the React FAQ [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html):

> props (short for “properties”) and state are both plain JavaScript objects. While both hold information that influences the output of render, they are different in one important way: props get passed to the component (similar to function parameters) whereas state is managed within the component (similar to variables declared within a function).

ReactJS actually doesn't offer an out of the box two way data binding.
Each react component can get props from it's parent. The props are one way data binding (`@` when creating an isolated scope in angular). You cant change the props from inside the component as props are read-only as written [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) in the react docs.
If you wish to change the props of your component you can use a callback function inside the props to change some value which is saved in the parent or any state management approach (Redux, MobX etc.).
Here's an example of the callback approach:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      counterForChildComponent: 0
    };

    this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
  }

  incrementCounter() {
    const newState = !this.state.isSearchOpen;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      counterForChildComponent: prevState + 1
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const {counterForChildComponent} = this.state;
    return (
      <ChildComponent counter={counterForChildComponent} incrementCounter={this.incrementCounter}
    );
  }
}
```

and child component:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => (
  <div onClick={props.incrementCounter}>{props.counter}</div>
);
```

That was about props. The `state` is actually meant to be a storage for data for the component's purpose. Changing the state results in a start of a specific lifecycle meant to update the view. 
If you're new to react I would recommend to see some important notices from the react docs about the state [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Hope I answered you'r question, feel free to ask here again.
Have fun. React is Fun.